# Push data from mongodb into a front-end array

Tags: express, ejs

I'm working on a simple node.js app that's storing data with mongodb. I'm not having any trouble adding new records to the database, or with displaying database records using ejs. However, I'd like to use data from my database (a list of words, incidentally) on the front end. Specifically, I'd like to push the results of a query into an array, which I can use in a front-end js file. Is this possible?

Here's the GET route:

```
 app.get("/wordlist", function (req, res) {
      Word.find({}, function(err, allWords){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          res.render("index", {words: allWords});
        }
      });
    });
```

And here's the simple loop I'm using to display the data in an ejs file:

```
<% words.forEach(function(foo){ %>
  <p><%= foo.word + " " + foo.category + " " + foo._id %></p>
<% }); %>
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: *Specifically, I'd like to push the results of a query into an array.* -- but it's already an array... `allWords` is an array that you stored in `words` that will be passed to your view, so `words` is an array. I don't follow.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner, so I'm sure I didn't ask correctly. Lemme try again.

I stored `allWords` in `words`, but I can only use that in my ejs markup. What I want is to be able to use the `words` variable in my plain old javascript file. In other words, if I type `words` into the browser console, I want to see the contents of the variable instead of getting a "not defined" error. Does that make sense? Or should I try again?

Comment: Ah! Front-end can mean many things hence the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, `<%- JSON.stringify(words) %>` should be enough but my IDE triggers an error without the extra logic because it doesn't know that `<%- ...  %>` resolves into an array of objects.

Also, note the use of `<%- unescaped %>` instead of `<%= escaped %>`.

```
<script>
    var words = JSON.parse('<%- JSON.stringify(words) %>');
    console.log(words);
</script>
```

Comment: Dude, you are the bomb dot com! Thank you so much!